# Autocompletebox as edit template in devexpress grid (silverlight)?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, devexpress

I am doin Silverlight app 4 using devexpress 11.

I have grid consiting of 4 coloums. i have placed autocompletebox as edit template in one of coloumn.

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid_presentingcomplaints">
                            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Complaints" Header="Complaints/Disease">
                                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditTemplate>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                           <sdk:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="t_comp" /> 
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditTemplate>
                                </dxg:GridColumn>
                                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Duration" Header="Duration (For)" />
                                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Period" FieldName="Period" />
                                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Details" FieldName="Details" />
                            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                <dxg:TableView Name="tableView3" ShowGroupPanel="False" NewItemRowPosition="Top" />
                            </dxg:GridControl.View>
                        </dxg:GridControl>
```

I would like to know how to set the autocompletebox itemsource? The grid is a binded to different itemsource.
Any ideas? if there is another way to accomplish this,please do mention

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind the `ItemsSource` to a collection in some kind of View Model try to bind to some higher level control's `DataContext` that contains your grid using `ElementName` in binding (maybe bind to the UserControl's `DataContext` directly). If the binding does not work (like it wouldn't in a standard SL data grid) refer to the [DataContextProxy](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx).

In case you are not using MVVM and binding you can just subscribe to the `Loaded` event of the `AutoCompleteBox` and set the `ItemsSource` there.